# fix django login bug

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm working on a django project, after I finished the code of registration and login feature (serializers and viewsets) I tested theses features, so when the registration feature seems working like a charm, the login feature bug,so when I try login with a registered user credetials I get this error message "detail": "No active account found with the given credentials"
I used django rest framework for the logic and rest framewok JWT for token authentication
HOw can I fix the bug?

I reviewed all the logic of authentication and permission , I axpect to fix the bug so I can login safely

Comment: Please share your code: serializers, viewsets and anything else relevant

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your viewset/serializer code and the error you're getting, it is hard to try to help you with this information. But the "No active account found with the given credentials" error is not saying that there isn't an account, it's saying no ACTIVE account so check if you have `is_active` field in your models and check if it's set to False then set it to True to fix the problem.